# Add black bar to an ion-card

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I have an ion-card with a header (title and subtitle) and I need to add a black bar on top of the header.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-card (click)="onEventClick(event.id)" *ngFor="let event of events">
      <ion-card-header>                                      
        <ion-card-subtitle>{{event.date}}</ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title style="font-size:15px" text-wrap>{{event.title}}</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>                        
    </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

This is what I want:

[image: want]

This is what I got so far:

[image: got]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem this way:

Just put this in the .scss file.

```css
ion-card{
    border-top: 10px solid brown;        
}

ion-card-header{
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: 00px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

[image: solved]

Comment: You just needed to add the `border-top`?

Answer (score 1):

1- make sure to set card header padding to zero

2- add a div as the first element in card-header with height > 0 and set the background to black color

[Sample result for below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiEYu.png)

```html
<ion-list>
        <ion-card (click)="onEventClick(event.id)" *ngFor="let event of events" >
          <ion-card-header style="padding: 0;">      
                <div style="height:15px;background:black;"></div>                  
            <ion-card-subtitle>{{event.date}}</ion-card-subtitle>
            <ion-card-title style="font-size:15px" text-wrap>{{event.title}}</ion-card-title>
          </ion-card-header>                        
        </ion-card>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: Thanks!

I tried here, the black bar is showing, but everything seems a little squeezed in the card, do you know why ?


https://i.imgur.com/0nXN2ks.png

Comment: I solved adding a border-top property in the scss file.

Thanks anyway :)